# Unable to insert a row in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008

Create Table customerinfo script

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[customerinfo](
    [customer#] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [acc#] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_unc_customerinfo] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [customer#] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [idx_u_customerinfo] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [acct#] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Reset the identity field with reseed 0, then i try to insert a rows in table. Getting Error as

```
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'idx_u_customerinfo'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.customerinfo'. The duplicate key value is (50950/01950).
```

How to rectify this issue.

Comment: Do you want yo be able to add duplicate values in column `acc#`?

Comment: Also the value you are adding looks like 11 characters and the column is only 10 characters. Perhaps you are getting duplicate values because the last character is cut off.

Comment: [customer#] is a primary key... It will not allow duplicate value

Comment: This is not related to the identity, the **acc#** seems to exist in the table. And if there is already data in the table why do you want reset the identity, this will also lead to trouble.

Comment: When you reseeded the identity column was your table empty or it's having some data already?

Comment: Some data's already, i deleted

Comment: Is this like you deleted all data then reseeded the column, then tried and inserted the new row and getting error. Or you reseeded the identity column , tried to insert new row, got error message, the deleted all data from table.

Comment: As you are getting error message 2627 .. you must check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176057(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

First: Your query is wrong.

`idx_u_customerinfo` is a unique nonclustered index on `acc#` or `acct#`. (`acct#` is't a field of your table).

Second: Check inserted data, Certainly you have multiple row with same `acc#`.

If you use `Insert Into [dbo].[customerinfo] Select ...` query for insert data to your table, use following query in order to find duplicate record:

```
Select acc#, count(*)
from ..
group by acc#
having count(*)<>1
```